# If I buy a game with a "non-tradable" coupon, is the game tradable?

Tags: steam

If I buy a game with a "non-tradable" coupon, can I trade the game?  E.g. can I technically buy the game using the coupon, and then sell it on ebay?

Comment: I presume the coupon is getting you the game to install and not a key that you can give away. Ergo, not sellable.

Comment: You can't sell steam games at all. You might be physically able to sell the product key, but I think this is techicnally illegal. You might be able to buy the game with the coupon as a gift and gift it to a friend on Steam, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not trade or sell games bought through the Steam store at all, regardless if you use a coupon. If you use the coupon and select "Buy as a gift" (instead of "Buy for myself"), you can gift the game to one of your friends. This feature does not provide any features or safeguards for a trade - it's a gift, meaning that you give something and get nothing in return.

Selling your games, if you found a way, is also against [the TOS of Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/) and will result in the shutdown of your account, and the loss of all licenses to games you previously owned. (emphasis mine)

> You are entitled to use the Content and Services for your own personal
>   use, but **you are not entitled to:** (i) **sell**, grant a security interest
>   in or transfer reproductions of **the Content and Services to other
>   parties in any way, nor to rent, lease or license the Content and
>   Services to others without the prior written consent of Valve, except
>   to the extent expressly permitted elsewhere in this Agreement
>   (including any Subscription Terms or Rules of Use);** (ii) host or
>   provide matchmaking services for the Content and Services or emulate
>   or redirect the communication protocols used by Valve in any network
>   feature of the Content and Services, through protocol emulation,
>   tunneling, modifying or adding components to the Content and Services,
>   use of a utility program or any other techniques now known or
>   hereafter developed, for any purpose including, but not limited to
>   network play over the Internet, network play utilizing commercial or
>   non-commercial gaming networks or as part of content aggregation
>   networks, websites or services, without the prior written consent of
>   Valve; or (iii) exploit the Content and Services or any of its parts
>   for any commercial purpose, except as expressly permitted elsewhere in
>   this Agreement (including any Subscription Terms or Rules of Use).